# jQuery Tools Overlay Re-positioning after ajax load

Tags: jquery, overlay, jquery-tools

I am creating a jquery tools overlay and i am loading in content on beforeLoad that changes the width of the overlay. Once i load the content, the width expands however the left position does not change. I want to be able to change the position so it is now centered instead of being more towards the right side of the screen. Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:** Here is my code below. I am first trying to get the width to register then i can use the function provided below to adjust the position. the code below returns a width of 470 which is the initial width of the overlay. After i load the content in, the real width is 740 however that alert always says 470

```
<div class="simple_overlay" id="test-overlay">  
<div class="details">
    <div id="overlayLoadingImg"><img id="overlayAnimatedGif" src="loading.gif"  alt="Loading" /></div>
</div>  
<a id="overlayClose" class="close">Close</a>        
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // if the function argument is given to overlay,
        // it is assumed to be the onBeforeLoad event listener
        $("a.overlay").live("click", function(){

            $(this).overlay({
                mask: {color: '#000',opacity: 0.5},
                top: "25%",
                effect: 'apple',
                load: true,
                closeOnClick: false,
                onBeforeLoad: function() {

                    //IE7 fix for z-index.
                       this.getOverlay().insertAfter('#exposeMask');
                    // grab wrapper element inside content
                    var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".details");

                    //check the datatype first. If iframe then load an iframe. If ajax then call the url via ajax call.
                    var dataurl = "http://someurl.com/path";


                    // load the page specified in the trigger   
                    $.ajax({
                          url: dataurl,
                          success: function(data){
                            $(wrap).html("");
                            $(wrap).append(data);

                            $(".closeOverlay").click(function(){
                                $("#overlayClose").click();
                            });

                            alert($("#test-overlay").width());

                          },
                          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                          }, 
                          complete: function(data){

                          }
                        });



                }

            });



     });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that sets the `left` CSS property of your overlay element dependent on the width of the screen and the width of the element, and then call that after setting the content in your AJAX callback.

Possibly something like this:

```
function setLeft(id) {
    var overlay = $('#' + id);
    var screenWidth = screen.width;
    var overlayWidth = overlay.width();
    var left = (screenWidth / 2 - overlayWidth / 2);
    overlay.css({left : left});
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UyrYx/)

Comment: Its detecting the size of the overlay before the content is loaded. Even though i put this code in the success function of the ajax call. Any idea?

Comment: @ScootaP Can you edit the question to include the code you've got right now?